# Injecting a service into a class not instantiated by NestJS (Trying to implement Colyseus + NestJS)

Tags: class, dependency-injection, nestjs, colyseus

I'm struggling to achieve a dependency injection inside a class not instantiated by NestJS.
I want to use the Colyseus Framework (https://colyseus.io/) in my NestJS project, and I need to inject services, for example for authenticating a client.

```
export class GameRoom extends Room<GameRoomState> {
    constructor (
        private authService: AuthService
    ) { super() }

    onCreate(options: any) {
        this.setState(new GameRoomState())
    }

    async onAuth(client: Client, options: any, request: IncomingMessage) {
        if (request.headers.cookies) {
            const sessionId = this.authService.getSessionId(request.headers.cookie)
            const user = await this.authService.authSessionId(sessionId)

            if (!user) {
                throw new ServerError(401, 'Invalid Session ID')
            }

            return true
        } else {
            throw new ServerError(401,'You need to provide a "session" cookie with a valid Session ID')
        }
    }
}
```

Then, if we pass the room class to the server' define function, it will instantiate it

```
this.server.define("GameRoom", GameRoom)
```

(https://docs.colyseus.io/server/api/#define-roomname-string-room-room-options-any)

The issue is that despite having a module that provides the AuthService and the GameRoom classes, when the server triggers the "onAuth" callback, this.authService will be undefined since the GameRoom used by the Colyseus server is not instantiated by Nest

Colyseus framework does not provide a way to define a room by passing a room instance, only a room type.
Is there any way to provide a service into my GameRoom class ? I don't see any way to do it since Nest is not instantiating it...
Huge thanks to anyone ready to help :)

I tried to modify the Colyseus package to imeplement a constructor that takes a Room instance instead of a type, but I'm a novice developper and I didn't succeed.
I tried many thing including property based injection, moduleRef with NestJS, but in the end nothing works because the Colyseus server does not use the same instance of the room as my module does

Answer (score 0):

My approach for this problem is to create a function that gets parameter types from Room class, then from these types, the dependencies can be retrieved through NextApplication instance.

here is the function I wrote

```js
function injectDeps<T extends { new (...args: any[]): Room }>(
  app: INestApplication,
  target: T,
): T {
  const selfDeps = Reflect.getMetadata('self:paramtypes', target) || [];
  const dependencies = Reflect.getMetadata('design:paramtypes', target) || [];

  selfDeps.forEach((dep: any) => {
    dependencies[dep.index] = dep.param;
  });

  const injectables =
    dependencies.map((dependency: any) => {
      return app.get(dependency);
    }) || [];

  return class extends target {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...injectables);
    }
  };
}
```

In this function, I used metadatakey `design:paramtypes` to get the types of all parameters in the Room class constructor.

The `self:paramtypes` is to retrieve parameter types that get injected with `@Inject()` decorator.

Then you can define it as follows,

```
  server.define('test', injectDeps(app, BaseRoom));
```

Note that, your room class have to be marked with `@Injectable()` decorator.

Here is [the example code](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/nestjs-forked-7qvkqm?workspaceId=fe4a6a7d-9f3f-442e-b578-0f943bd6c919&embed=1&file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.ts&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszx6szg00073b6gyluo4ykf%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszx6szf00023b6gshokqpcx%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszx6szf00043b6gc202612u%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszx6szf00063b6gr1wol00b%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clszx6szf00023b6gshokqpcx%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszx6szf00023b6gshokqpcx%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clszxcsaw00v53b6gdude4vbg%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszx7cj9003o3b6g1my696tb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Fmain.ts%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252F.codesandbox%252Ftasks.json%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszxcsaw00v53b6gdude4vbg%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clszx6szf00063b6gr1wol00b%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszx6szf00063b6gr1wol00b%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszxcpmt00tj3b6g9fu8iqfb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522https%253A%252F%252F7qvkqm-3000.csb.app%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clszxcpmt00tj3b6g9fu8iqfb%2522%257D%252C%2522clszx6szf00043b6gc202612u%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszx6szf00043b6gc202612u%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clszx6szf00033b6g03k39v05%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clszx6szf00033b6g03k39v05%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D).